# rendering depth images non consecutive frames -via python

Tags: python, rendering

I refered to this post in the following link
and I know this is usually done with

```
 scene.render.filepath = fp + str(frame_nr)
 bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) # render still
```

from : [Python Render Specific Frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/python-render-specific-frames/17840#17840)
However, this only stores the colour images. Not the Z buffer lined to a path. How can I do it?

could any one please tell me how to do it for the **depth** images?

Comment: Normally blender only saves the final result. You can use a [file output node](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74131/935) to automate saving any other render data to file.

Comment: Yes , but I need to change the name of the file.I can only change the basepath if I am using outputnodes , not the file names

Comment: The base path is the top directory of all files and is added to the beginning of the subpath for each connection. The subpath uses the same filename rules as the [normal render output settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel), which adds the frame number to the filename. If you really need it, you could change the file output node settings before rendering each frame.

Comment: AttributeError: 'CompositorNodeOutputFile' object has no attribute 'sub_path'

Comment: The [output file node](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.CompositorNodeOutputFile.html) has the `base_path` and `file_slots` which is a list of connections that contain the subpath in their [path property](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.NodeOutputFileSlotFile.html#bpy.types.NodeOutputFileSlotFile.path) - `fnode.file_slots[0].path='filename'`