# How to render 3 different scenes in one shot?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have 3 scenes in my file, one with the background in 24fps rendering and the camera moving, another with the animated characters rendered in 12 fps, another with just the shadow of my character. I would like to render my 3 scenes separately, in 3 different folders to recomposition the whole in the video editing but I need to render my scene one by one. How can I render 3 different scenes by only throwing the rendering once?

Comment: Add another scene, switch to the compositor workspace - add 3 different render layer nodes to the compositor and use one or multiple file output node(s) depending on how the output should be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I batch render multiple scenes with animation settings?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/how-do-i-batch-render-multiple-scenes-with-animation-settings)

Comment: Yes and no because the problem is that the rendering continues after the end of the 12fps animation rendering because the 24fps is longer. Do you know if there’s an alternative to that?

Comment: Either render the 12fps shot(s) seperatly, save a new blend file containing equal frame rates and render it on another machine or just use the command line: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes ... hundreds of possibilities depending on your setup.

Comment: The answer corresponds to my expectations thank you!